# How to consume fixed messages per time on RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Currently, I'm using the `spring-boot-starter-amqp` module and can use the annotation `@RabbitListener` to read messages on background, How can I consume a fixed number of messages from a queue only when a method is called?

What I'm trying to build is an "on-demand" consumer for a queue, I'll receive an HTTP request on an endpoint with the number of messages and I want to consume only this amount defined.

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose you must not use a `@RabbitListener`, but rather a dedicated API for on-demand receive. See `RabbitTemplate`:

```
/**
 * Receive a message if there is one from a default queue. Returns immediately,
 * possibly with a null value.
 *
 * @return a message or null if there is none waiting
 * @throws AmqpException if there is a problem
 */
@Nullable
Message receive() throws AmqpException;
```

To optimize this call for a batch request you may consider to use a scoped operation:

```
/**
 * Invoke the callback and run all operations on the template argument in a dedicated
 * thread-bound channel and reliably close the channel afterwards.
 * @param action the call back.
 * @param <T> the return type.
 * @return the result from the
 * {@link OperationsCallback#doInRabbit(RabbitOperations operations)}.
 * @throws AmqpException if one occurs.
 * @since 2.0
 */
@Nullable
default <T> T invoke(OperationsCallback<T> action) throws AmqpException {
```

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#amqp-template